# Working rails app in GitHub when cloned, bundled, db:migrated, then fails on different machine. Why"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

Built rails app on os x 10.12.6 using Rails 5.2.2.1.  It works fine. Pushed it to GitHub repository.  Then on my other Mac running os x 10.13.6 using rails 5.2.2.1 cloned the app from the GitHub repository.  After cloning, I did a bundle, followed by rails db:migrate, all of which worked.  Then after starting the rails server, http://localhost:3000 gives:

```
Showing /Users/woo/Development/rails/blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #8 raised:

Rails.root: /Users/woo/Development/rails/blog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
(execjs):1
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2007388718642651482_70169116884640'
```

I see no hints as to what is actually wrong.  If I comment out the two lines in app/views/layout/application.html.erb below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Blog</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= render "layouts/header" %>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render "layouts/footer" %>
  </body>
</html>
```

That do the stylesheet_link_tag and the java_script_include_tag, then I don't get the failure, but don't get the styling or javascript either!

What is different when one clones and tries to get it running?  What should I be looking for?

Comment: I have now completely reinstalled Xcode, developer tools, ruby, rails, and restarted the app.  Same results.

Comment: Created rails new test app, then rails g scaffold Post title:string test:string.  Then ran rails db:migrate, then rails s.  SAME error!  Ruby 2.6.0 is version.  Shouldn't a simple test app work?  What am I missing?

Comment: Did rails db:migrate work correctly? Did you miss creating the database?

Comment: No, the db:migrate worked fine.  What would cause those statements to be the problem?  I've gone through a complete reinstallation of brew, ruby, rum, etc and then when I try to create a new simple test app, it fails the same way.  What things must have exactly the same version numbers, etc?

Comment: I don't think you need the exact same versions. It would tell you in the error message if this was the case. Also you have the package manager for that.
Is this the whole error message?

Comment: yes.  I'm trying now to get the same ruby version 2.3.1 instead of 2.6.  I get information that railties isn't installed and that OpenSSL isn't and i need to recompile ruby.  Working my way through that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this working. Had to use sudo to install rvm again, then everything started working better. rvm reload followed by rvm use ruby --install --default --create. then cd'd to project, bundle, db:migrate, and rails s and all was okay. Not sure why had to sudo to install rvm correctly. must have a permission wrong somewhere there.

Comment: I have also discovered the "laptop" script by monfresh at:
https://github.com/monfresh/laptop